# Insert other value in List for remaining places to avoid Index out of bounds exception

Tags: java

I am traversing through two lists whose size does not match. One list size is greater than the other. Say List A has five objects in it and List B has two, then my code works for only two objects in List B avoiding three others in List A. I wanted to add some constant value in that list for that List A. Below is the code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < filteredStartDate.size(); i++) {
            // Long sum = null;
            if ((fsFFDB.size() != listHoldingsDBRecords.size())
                    && (filteredStartDate.get(i)
                            .isBefore(filteredEndDate.get(i)))) {

                try {
                    tosValues.add(fsFFDB.get(i).getFloatShares());
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    tosValues.add(fsFFDB.get(fsFFDB.size()-1).getFloatShares());
                }
            } else if ((fsFFDB.size() == listHoldingsDBRecords.size())
                    && (filteredStartDate.get(i).isBefore(filteredEndDate.get(i)))) {
                tosValues.add(fsFFDB.get(i).getFloatShares());
            }
            
        }
```

Currently, I have a filteredStartDate list size which is 3 and the fsFFDB size list is 2. So it was straightforward, the last record will remain vacant and will throw Index out of bounds exception. I have caught the exception and then in the catch block, I have inserted the constant value which is fsFFDB.size()-1).getFloatShares(). But what I want is to say if filteredStartDate size is 5 and fsFFDB size is 1, then for the remaining four records also the constant value should be inserted. I want my code to be dynamic. Please help. Can we replace all other values in list with some constant?

Comment: Would the constant value be the last available one? Or where would you get the constant?

Comment: @Pratik please clarify your requirement: do you want that in the smaller list random element is added so its length is equal to the larger list or do you want that the remaining elements of the longer list must be computed after the smaller one runs out of elements?

Comment: Remaining ones.

Answer (score 0):

To start off, using Exceptions for normal operation is not good practice, and it will be bad for performance. A better idea is to detect when you are out of elements in one list by comparing your current index against the length of the list. Here is an example:

```java
List<Integer> a = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5);
List<Integer> b = Arrays.asList(6,7,8);
List<Integer> c = new ArrayList<>();
int aConst = 9;
int bConst = 10;
for(int i = 0; i < a.size() || i < b.size(); i++) {
    c.add(
        (i < a.size() ? a.get(i) : aConst) +
        (i < b.size() ? b.get(i) : bConst)
    );
}
```

Comment: The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) Object & Serializable & Comparable<? extends Comparable<?>>, Serializable getting this error

Comment: I tried this for(int i = 0; i < filteredStartDate.size() || i < fsFFDB.size(); i++) {
      tosValues.add(
          (i < filteredStartDate.size() ? filteredStartDate.get(i) : fsFFDB.get(fsFFDB.size()-1).getFloatShares()) +
          (i < fsFFDB.size() ? fsFFDB.get(i) : fsFFDB.get(fsFFDB.size()-1).getFloatShares())
      );
  }

Comment: @PratikPathare Using addition (+) was just an example combiner function. You can use a different function to get the correct value to put in list c.

Comment: Which one? Can you please suggest?

Comment: You essentially have 3 cases to consider: 1) What do you add to list `c` when there are remaining elements in both `a` and `b`? 2) What do you add to `c` when  `a` has elements remaining and `b` is out of elements? 3) What do you add to `c` when `a` is out of elements and `b` has elements remaining? You then need to set up some conditionals to determine what case you fall into and act accordingly.

Comment: How should I frame the code for 2nd case? When a has elements and b is out of elements.

Comment: As I said, you need to figure that out.